# convert pdf to image and display the image ionic 1

Tags: html, css, angularjs, pdf, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 1.I have the pdf url link. where i need to convert my pdf in to images and need to display . How can i handle this. Any idea please code example or tutorial will be help full.

```
I haven't see any tutorial and i have asked some pos .But still now not able to find the solution.
```

Thanks